# Axios error in Nuxtjs in testing with Jest

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs, axios, nuxt.js

I want to test my code with Jest and when I call my function in code get a error in `this.$axios`

```
TypeError: this.$axios is not a function
```

How can I fix it with mock or other way?

Comment: This means that you must have axios as a plugin. Have you created a plugin for this? If yes then that file is to be mentioned in the "plugins" parameter of nuxt.config.js. Moreover, can you please consider providing some code for us to look into?